# Meaning x"00" in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, bit

In  VHDL-simulation, there is the following line

```
signal SigA: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)   := x"00";
...
if Rst = '1' then
  sigA<=    x"00";
```

`SigA` is 8 bits  vector and I assume `x"00"` is a representation of `0` in 8 bits, right?

Could someone explain how this representaion was done?

I have 6 bits vector and need to represent `0` as 6 bits as well.

Comment: @user16145658 So I can just write `sigA<= (others => '0') ;` and it will be the same as if i write `sigA<=    x"00";`, right?

Comment: It's a bit string literal,  type taken from context. In -2008 a bit string literal could have an integer length prefix, here before the  base (x) providing a binary length allowing shortening. There's also an aggregate `(others => '0')` as the initial value expression, which takes it's subtype from context as well. For something with a length of 6 it would provide a value with all six elements being '0'. You could provide a string literal "000000", whose type is taken from context. ... See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.7/8 String literals/Bit string literals and 9.3.2 Literals, 9.3.3 Aggregates.

Answer (score 5):

This is what is refered to as a "bit string literal". any string inside "" can be assumed to be a bit string literal in the correct context.

Bit string literals can be applied to any array of type bit or std_(u)logic. So for bit_vector, only 0/1 chars may be used, but for std_logic_vector, which has 9 state types, any of these can be used. For example :

`my_9bit_slv <= "U01WLHZX-";`

NOTE: you are allowed to use _ to help with logical groupings chars. eg:

`my_16bit_slv <= "0000_1111_0000_1111";`

VHDL before 2008 defines 3 items you can pre-pend to the string to change the meaning:

x"" = hexadecimal. Chars here can only be 0-9 or A-F (pre 2008). This is 4 bits per char

o"" = octal. As above, chars can only be 0-7 (pre 2008). This is 3 bits per char

b"" = binary (the default). 1 bit per char

VHDL 2008 improved bit string literals in several ways:

In Hex and octal, you can now use the chars X, W, L H, -, U, Z to represent 4/3 bits of that char

you can specify the length of the literal by preceding the o/x/b with the total number of bits, and it will fit the value directly to the array. The rules for this are that the unused bits MUST be 0, or you get a syntax error

For example:

`my_6bit_slv := 6x"3F"; -- ok`

`my_6bit_slv := 6x"FF"; -- syntax error, the 2 MSBs are 1, and wont fit into the array`

In addition, you can provide the letters s and u to specify whether the number is "signed" or "unsigned". "signed" will take the MSB as the sign bit and fill the value to the object being assigned:

`my_6bit_slv := 6sx"F"; -- assigns 111111 to my_6bit_slv as it sign extends x"F" to 6 bits`

3. You can now use d to represent a decimal number:

`my_6bit_slv := 6d"10"; -- assigns 001010 to my_6bit_slv`